# use EOS as private blockchain for a loyalty system

Tags: smart-contract, dapp, blockchains

We are working on a loyalty system powered by blockchain. Using blockchain enables us to have basic security at the beginning and scale easily. it makes total sense to us.

the loyalty system will launch on top of a online store builder service. so, at launch it will have hundreds of shops. each shop has it's own points and they can be isolated loyalty system or points can be shared with other shops. I'm thinking we need a smart contract for each shops because each one may need a different point-based reward system.

We probably need a private blockchain for this. I was wondering if we can fork EOS for this? do you think EOS is too much or a perfect fit?

if it is a good fit, how can we fork it and run our own private blockchain? do we need to remove unnecessary parts of EOS?

I did not find any tutorial for running a fork of EOS. can anyone help?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can fork EOS for this.  Think of EOS as an inherently flexible operating system layer for blockchain based applications.  If you look at the chain **[config.hpp](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/libraries/chain/include/eosio/chain/config.hpp)** file, you can see some of the basic flexibility you can change for your own needs.:

Example changing block interval:

```
const static int      block_interval_ms = 500; // half second blocks
```

---

Here is an example of a fork: https://github.com/Telos-Foundation/telos

If your project is as large as you say, I would recommend contacting block one's developer support directly: **[developers@block.one](https://block.one/contact/)**

Comment: thanks for your answer. How about removing things like governance and voting? I'm not totally aware of all the features of EOS and how to remove them. We don't need many of them I assume